# Can i redraw the UI inside an operator?

Tags: python, scripting, interface, operator

I have a script which is working. At the end of the script, rendering is started. This is supposed to work as a template for people possibly unfamiliar with a freezing screen (blender is loading lots of data into cache from images used in the compositor). 
For that reason i want an "Info" in the top bar saying something like "This might take a while. Now rendering...".
So i would have this in my operator

- draw message
- redraw UI (to show message)
- Run the rest of the script

Is this possible?

Comment: see this Q/A http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28673/update-viewport-while-running-script

Comment: also related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3219/how-to-show-to-the-user-a-progression-in-a-script

Answer (score 1):

use `report()` in your operator to display reports on the top bar

```
self.report({'INFO'},"This ma take some time")
# rest of the code here
```

Comment: Yeah, but I'm pretty sure that the UI isn't redrawn until after the python is done executing. I could be wrong about this, but I'm pretty sure that's the case.

Comment: @TARDISMaker I have already linked to the force redraw solution ( in the comments ) and this answer is about the report()