# Update Edge Info when using script in Edit Mode

Tags: python, scripting, edit-mode

I'm editing a mesh using a script, while in Edit Mode. I need to display the Edge Angles while editing, but these don't get updated until I leave and re-enter Edit Mode.

Is there a function I can call to force updating the displayed Edge Angles while staying in Edit Mode?

Minimal example (slightly edited from "Bmesh Simple Editmode":

```
# This example assumes we have a mesh object in edit-mode

import bpy
import bmesh

# Get the active mesh
obj = bpy.context.edit_object
me = obj.data


# Get a BMesh representation
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

bm.faces.active = None

# Modify the BMesh, can do anything here...
bm.verts[0].co.x -= 1.0


# Show the updates in the viewport
# and recalculate n-gon tessellation.
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me, True)
```

[image]

Comment: 2.78.5 2.79 - in this versions I haven't this problem. Maybe you need to update Blender?

Comment: @batFINGER have you tried official blender build from blender.org?

Comment: @batFinger: Thanks for the info. I'm currently using an official Blender 2.78c build on Linux 64bit. I'll give the official 2.79 version a shot tonight, and file a bug report if the behaviour is still there.

Comment: @batFINGER for bug report you need to know what versions has this. Now I have no idea about that.

Comment: I've opened a [bug report](https://developer.blender.org/T53876)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Need to update the normals.**

Thanks to the information in the [invalid bug report](https://developer.blender.org/T53876) the angle info needed requires the face normals.  This can be achieved by calling [`Bmesh.normal_update()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bmesh.types.html#bmesh.types.BMesh.normal_update)

```
# This example assumes we have a mesh object in edit-mode

import bpy
import bmesh

# Get the active mesh
obj = bpy.context.edit_object
me = obj.data

# Get a BMesh representation
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

bm.faces.active = None

# Modify the BMesh, can do anything here...
bm.verts[0].co.x -= 1.0

# recalculate normals.
bm.normal_update()
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me, True)
```

or by calling  [`BMFace.normal_update()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bmesh.types.html#bmesh.types.BMFace.normal_update) for each affected face. Simple example on all faces.

```
# recalculate normals.
for f in bm.faces:
    f.normal_update()
```

PS. not the normal avenue to come to a solution, and apologies for suggesting the dud bug report. *(Another Doh moment on reading bug report lol)*

Answer (score 4):

I'm trying to guess why you need to stay in edit mode. If it isn't critical you can add,

```
bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
```

(both lines) before the call to update. This is essentially doing in code what you do manually in the gif - flipping from object back to edit mode to update the display of length values.

Updating the 3d view is also covered in this answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28673/update-viewport-while-running-script)

[image]