# bmesh.ops.inset_region gives unexpected results

Tags: python

I want to create an object based on the active one with inset faces and modified vertex coordinates. Inset works as expected if I don't modify verts coordinates but if I do it gives me unexpected results. Do I need to somehow "recalculate" bmesh after I modify verts positions?

Here's the result I'm getting:

[image]

Here's a code I run on a Plane object. As an example I make every point of the object 1 unit higher. I tried to include different variants of `.ensure_lookup_table()` without any luck.

```py
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Vector

ob = bpy.context.object
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(ob.data)

for index, v in enumerate(bm.verts):
   v.co = v.co + Vector((0,0,index))

# insetting bmesh
inset_faces = bmesh.ops.inset_region(bm, faces = bm.faces, thickness=0.5, use_boundary=True, use_even_offset=True)

# creating mesh
mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new("mesh")
obj = bpy.data.objects.new("new_obj", mesh)
bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(obj)

bm.to_mesh(obj.data)
obj.data.update()
bm.free()
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update the normals.**

After you "twist" face by index translation, the normals are not recalculated unless we explicitly call `normal_update` either on the bmesh instance, or on a per face basis.

[Update Edge Info when using script in Edit Mode](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98863/update-edge-info-when-using-script-in-edit-mode)

Script with that edit, also optionally changed operator to inset individual.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Vector

ob = bpy.context.object
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(ob.data)

for v in bm.verts:
   v.co.z += v.index
   
# update the normals
bm.normal_update()
# or on per face
'''
for f in bm.faces:
    f.normal_update()
'''
# insetting bmesh
inset_faces = bmesh.ops.inset_individual(
        bm, 
        faces=bm.faces, 
        thickness=0.5,
        #use_interpolate=True,
        use_even_offset=True)

# creating mesh
mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new("mesh")
obj = bpy.data.objects.new("new_obj", mesh)
bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(obj)

bm.to_mesh(obj.data)
obj.data.update()
bm.free()
```

[image]

Comment: That's what I was missing! Thank you!