# How to force update the 3d view port in blender during python file execution

Tags: python, rendering, 3d-view

I am trying to connect a physical robot arm with its digital replica using blender I am able to communicate between the two using MQTT but the changes in blender are reflected only when the python script associated with it completes execution but I want the change to be seen as soon as the value is received by blender, ie, updating the viewport before complete execution.
I have tried using: bpy.ops.wm.redraw_timer and bpy.scene.update() but this doesn't work in my case, I even tried the solution given in [Update viewport while running script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28673/update-viewport-while-running-script)
but it doesn't really help me. Here is my code snippet, can someone please tell what is wrong and how to update the viewport?
PS- Blender version is 2.8.0
Thank you in advance:)
import bpy
import json
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt 
from math import radians
from math import pi  # It's considered bad practice to import everything from a library, especially when you're not using any (or just a few) of its function

```
import mathutils 
from mathutils import Euler
def changes(a,b,c):
    Shouldercord1=pi*(92.3/180)
    Shouldercord2=pi*(a/180) #to be changed
    Shouldercord3=pi*(62.2/180)
    obj=bpy.data.objects['Arm 01']
    obj.rotation_euler = Euler((Shouldercord1,Shouldercord2 ,Shouldercord3) , 'XYZ')

    Waistcord1=pi*(-269/180)
    Waistcord2=pi*(0.642/180)
    Waistcord3=pi*(b/180) #to be changed
    obj2=bpy.data.objects['Waist']
    obj2.rotation_euler = Euler((Waistcord1,Waistcord2 ,Waistcord3) , 'XYZ')

    Armcord1=pi*(261/180)
    Armcord2=pi*(c/180) #to be changed
    Armcord3=pi*(-128/180)
    obj3=bpy.data.objects['Arm 02 v3']
    obj3.rotation_euler = Euler((Armcord1,Armcord2 ,Armcord3) , 'XYZ')



def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("\tMQTT Server Connected code "+str(rc))
    client.subscribe('blender/test')
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    message = (msg.payload)
   #print(message)
   #sys.exit(0) 
    result=json.loads(message)
    a= result["a"]
    b= result["b"]
    c= result["c"]
    changes(a,b,c)   
client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect

client.username_pw_set("xxxx","xxxx")
client.connect("xxxx", 1883, xx)
client.on_message = on_message
client.loop_forever()
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer, threading can be used

```
def my_timer():
    from threading import Timer
    main();
    #print(i);
    t = Timer(0.1, my_timer)
    t.start()
```

Hope this helps, we took a lot of time to come up with it