# problem during script execution

Tags: python, scripting, command-line

hi I wrote a simple script to take screenshots, but the frames are not updating in the screenshots i.e all screenshots are the same image (a single frame). I introduced a time delay in case blender having problem updating but the problem is still there

```
import bpy
import pyautogui
import time
c=1
while c<=50:
    bpy.context.scene.frame_current =c
    time.sleep(2)
    path='D:\\Blender\\script_screenshot\\'+str(c)+'.png'
    pyautogui.screenshot(path)
    c=c+5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blender doesn't update the GUI by default when a script is running. See [Update viewport while running script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/28689/33589)

Add `bpy.ops.wm.redraw_timer(type='DRAW_WIN_SWAP', iterations=1)` after you change frames to update the GUI.

Also, you can take Blender screenshots with a BPY op like this `bpy.ops.screen.screenshot( filepath=path, check_existing=False)` so you might not need pyautogui.

```
import bpy
#import pyautogui
import time
c=1
while c<=50:
    bpy.context.scene.frame_current =c
    bpy.ops.wm.redraw_timer(type='DRAW_WIN_SWAP', iterations=1)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    path='C:\\tmp\\script_screenshot\\'+str(c)+'.png'
#    pyautogui.screenshot(path)
    bpy.ops.screen.screenshot( filepath=path, check_existing=False)
    c=c+5
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: If Ron's answer has solved your issue, please consider to accept the answer @Ali Thanks. See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers